# ssl certification : common name is correct on server but incorrect on website

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have an old sub domain : `api.example.com` and a ssl certification with it ( Now i am using `letsencrypt` and `nginx` ). Then i created a new sub domain for it `internship.example.com` and generated a new ssl certification for it. But when i check on website , it shows this error:

`Certificate does not match name internship.example.com`.On website, SSL Common name is : `Common Name = api.example.com` But when i show common name on server by command :

`sudo openssl x509 -noout -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/internship.example.com/fullchain.pem -subject -issuer -dates`

it is correct :

```
subject= /CN=internship.example.com
issuer= /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
notBefore=Apr 13 01:02:00 2017 GMT
notAfter=Jul 12 01:02:00 2017 GMT
```

This is nginx config file :

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name internship.example.com;
   #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   #index index.html index.htm;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/internship.example.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/internship.example.com/privkey.pem;

   location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
                      proxy_http_version 1.1;
                      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                      proxy_set_header Host $host;
                      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

So why it is incorrect on website ? can someone explain it for me?

Comment: well, Pls help me !!!

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to test and list your actual configuration.